# Get data from multiple references from Firebase realtime database in one query javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

On photo below you can see my data structure.

I want to get the required data from the messages object in one request.
For example:

```
firebase.database().ref('messages/' + "-Me4yNAigYmM5_PhuiIS", 'messages/' + -Me4yNoy8n971XMwnxqP).get();
```

expected output:

```
{
   -Me4yNAigYmM5_PhuiIS: {
       text: example;
   },
   -Me4yNoy8n971XMwnxqP: {
       text: example2;
   },
}
```

I got out of the situation like this:

```
   useEffect(() => {
    const usersMessages = firebase.database().ref("users/" + userUid + "/messages");
    usersMessages.on('value', async (snapshot) => {
        let usersMessages = [];
        const messages = (await firebase.database().ref("messages/").get()).val();
       
        snapshot.val().map(messageId => {
            usersMessages.push(messages[messageId]);
        });
    });
}, []);
```

How correct is it to constantly load all messages of all users? Is there a way to get only the required messages from Firestone in one request, knowing a few message IDs?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load multiple nodes based on their key, you'll need a separate call for each node/key. It's essentially a client-side join of the data from the two nodes:

```
const usersMessages = firebase.database().ref(`users/${userUid}/messages`);
usersMessages.on('value', async (snapshot) => {
    let usersMessages = [];
    snapshot.forEach((child) => }
        let messageId = child.key;
        let messageSnapshot = await firebase.database().ref(`messages/${messageId}`).get()
        const message = messageSnapshot.val();
        usersMessages.push(message);   
    });
});
```

Comment: All the same, we use one request for each message?

Comment: Yes. Contrary to what you may think, this is not necessarily slower than doing them in a single request, as Firebase can pipeline the requests over a single connection. To learn more about this, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786